# Coerce object into list with one element in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

First off, I know this is bad practice but I'm constrained to only having access to the template layer of a Django project so here goes.

So say I have list1, and list2 which both contain story objects. I also have featured_story which is a single story object. In my template I can do teh following.

```
{% with list1|add:list2 as my_list %}
# my_list is now all elements from list1 and list2
{% with my_list|add:featured_story as final_list %}
# my_list has not changed
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Is there a way to coerce featured_story into a list?

Again, I know I shouldn't be doing this and given the ability would take care of this in the view layer but I'm using the Ellington platform and do not have access to the appropriate code to be able to add this. Alternately I also do not have the ability to create a custom tag or filter that would facilitate this.

Comment: So... why can't you handle `featured_story` separately in the template?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is a very simplified example. these lists and that object are actually members of an object i have to access through a template tag, I can handle it separately but each of the displays will use the exact same template. I also have to do this about 5 times. It would be easier if I could just build one big list. Again, I know this is BAD practice but this is where I am and currently without one big list the markup is kind of a pain and would be dificult to maintain.

Comment: Even with the use of `{% include %}`?

Comment: Include sounds like a good idea..